# How to remove a link file that available in directory?

Tags: apache

Hi Friends I have link in "mentortask" with in the folder of "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/" when I was try to delete that file using following command. it can't work and said can not remove permission denied when I am reload the apache server.

" **rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mentortask.com** " and
 " **unlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mentortask.com** "

How will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mentortask.com
```

If you can't, then you need to petition the administrator to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

find ./{DirectoryName} -type l -print0 | xargs -0 ls -plah |tr -s ' '  | cut -f9 -d ' ' | xargs rm -rf